# adding UIPageViewController to a view controller's container view

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I'm trying to Add my pageViewController to a container view on my main viewController . For that , I have added these codes

```
  addChildViewController(pageViewController!)
   self.sliderView.addSubview(pageViewController!.view)
  pageViewController!.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

But when I run the app ,it's looks like this :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Sf17.jpg

I want to add my pageViewController in the yellow containerView which name is sliderView .

What's wrong with that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more code as the given example code works pretty well.

Possible causes could be the forced unwrap of your `pageViewController`. Additionally ensure that the controller is properly instantiated from Storyboard like

```
guard let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("YourViewControllerID") as? YourViewControllerClass else
{
    return
}
sliderView.addSubview(vc.view)
vc.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

You can set `YourViewControllerID` directly within the Storyboards Identity Inspector